# JavaServiceWrapper on 64bit linux, any problems?

Tags: java, daemon

We've been using the 32bit linux version of the [JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/) for quite a while now and it's working perfectly. We are now considering also using it on 64bit linux systems. There are downloads for 64bit binaries on the website, but looking into Makefile for the 64bit version I found the following comment, though: 
    # This makefile is in progess. It builds, but the resulting libwrapper.so does not yet work.
    # If you know how to fix it then please help out.

Can anyone confirm, that this comment is just outdated and the resulting wrapper will work without flaws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had it running in production on 64-bit red hat without any trouble for the last year or so.

Comment: I accepted your answer because you're the first with real life experience (besides ourselves, we have it running in the mean time too :-)

Answer (score 1):

From http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/introduction.html :

> Binary distributions are provided for
>   the following list of platforms and
>   are available on the download page.
>   Only OS versions which are known to
>   work have been listed.
>
> (snip...)
>
> - linux - Linux kernels; 2.2.x 2.4.x, 2.6.x. Known to work with Debian and Red Hat, but should work with any
>     distribution. Currently supported on
>     both 32 and **64-bit** x86, and 64-bit ppc
>     systems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/.

It's free and rather compatible reimplementation of TanukiSoftware Java Service Wrapper featuring free 64-bit support.